# How Angular4 site can indexed by Google?

Tags: angular, seo, angular-material, permalinks

How all pages of https://material.angular.io can be indexed by google?
check it: https://www.google.co.id/webhp?hl=id&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIu4_2mu3UAhWHKo8KHVk-AagQPAgD#hl=id&q=site:material.angular.io

As you see, that site is using **Angular4** (view source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using Angular Universal with NodeJS as their web server. Universal allows Angular websites to be indexed by web crawlers.

There is a website for universal:

https://universal.angular.io/

Comment: does it still need prerenderer or not? hopefully PHP support for Angular Universal will be release near future... Thanks for your info..

Comment: It doesn't pre-render the HTML. The Angular application is bootstrap into NodeJS. Components are run in response to the routes and a DOM emulator is used. The app will only work is you follow the expected pattern required for Universal.  I would recommend using REST/JSON calls in the Angular app to a PHP server. PHP wouldn't care if it's a browser or Universal making the request.